# How to find/extract a pattern from a file?

Tags: regex, bash, unix

Here are the contents of my text file named 'temp.txt'

```
---start of file ---
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  b687

Capturing... done
Storing... done
---end of file ----
```

I want to write a bash script in which I need to capture the string 'b687' in a variable.  this is really a pattern (which is the letter 'b' followed by 'n' number of digits).  I can do it the hard way by looping through the file and extracting the desired string (b687 in example above).  Is there an easy way to do so?  Perhaps by using awk or sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `grep`

```
v=$(grep -oE '\bb[0-9]{3}\b' file)
```

This will seach for a word starting with `b` followed by '3' digits.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gF8gZ8)

---

Using `sed`

```
v=$(sed -nr 's/.*\b(b[0-9]{3})\b.*/\1/p' file)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The grep command works.  Question: what do '\b' in the start and end of the regular expression are for?

Comment: @Bharat `\b` specifies word boundary, if not present it will also match `123b687123` which I think is not desired. Provided regex101 demo has regular expression explained. Please check.

Comment: Thanks again for taking time out to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
varname=$(awk '/HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL/{print $4}' filename)
```

what this does is reads the file when it matches the pattern HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL print the 4th token in this case b687

---

your other option is to use sed

```
varname=$(sed -n 's/.* \(b[0-9][0-9]*\)/\1/p' filename)
```

In this case we are looking for the pattern you mentioned b####... and only print that pattern  the -n tells sed not to print line that do not have that pattern. the rest of the sed command is a substitution .* is any string at the beginning. followed by a (...) which forms a group in which we put the regex that will match your b##### the second part says out of all that match only print the group 1 and the p at the end tells sed to print the result (since by default we told sed not to print with the -n)